# Assignment operator prevents concatenation

Tags: powershell, active-directory, concatenation

I have AD groups named `xxx16up, yyy16up, zzz16up`. What I'm trying to do is if:

- AD user is grade level 16 and up
- AD user is not yet a member of said group

the script will add the AD user to the corresponding group based on company codes xxx, yyy, zzz.

```
$list = Import-CSV "C:\update12Apr2018.csv"

foreach ($company in $list) {
    $myList = ( Get-ADGroup "$($company.comp)16up" ).DistinguishedName
    if ( ([INT]$_.level -ge 16) -and (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!(memberof=$myList))" )) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($company.comp)16up" -Members $company.samAccountName
    }
}
```

The part highlighted does not work within the code. But if I take it out and run it by itself it has no problems. It produces the corresponding group of either `xxx16up, yyy16up, or zzz16up.`

Within the code, it gave below error:

> *Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: '16up' under: 'DC=ACME,DC=com'. At line:1 char:33
>   + ... ch ($company in $list) { ( Get-ADGroup "$($company.comp)16up" ).Disti ...
>   +                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (16up:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manag
>   ement.Commands.GetADGroup*

I was able to narrow down the problem to when there is an assignment operation and that is when it acts as if the concatenation failed.

Comment: It's not the assignment that's failing. It's the call to `Get-ADGroup` that fails because it can't find a group "16up". I suspect you have a bad entry in your csv file where the Comp property is empty.

Comment: Appearently `$company.comp` is empty. The most likely cause is that you do not have access to the `:\update12Apr2018.csv` in the environment where your cmdlet runs.

Comment: Even if you solve your main issue, the code isn't going to work as you expect since `$_` doesn't exist inside `foreach` except on a pipeline: `([INT]$_.level -ge 16)`

Comment: i isolated that concatenation code by removing the assignment part and it works. all my $company.comp in the CSV are filled. no empty slot. like i mentioned above, it only fails when i place the code to the right-side of an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach ($company in $list) {
    $groupName = $company.comp + '16up'
    $myList = ( Get-ADGroup $groupName ).DistinguishedName
```

see the sleight of hand? ;-)